# PHPCi and symfony2 request tests

Tags: php, symfony

I have PHPCi on my server and symfony2 project. When i run build the project i get this error from phpunit:

*Failure: ApiBundle\Tests\Controller\BooksControllerTest::testBooksAction
Failed asserting that 500 matches expected 200.*

But if i run in console: `$ phpunit -c app/` - all ok, i not get errors
Can someone faced with this?

My BooksControllerTest.php:

```
<?php
namespace ApiBundle\Tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class BooksControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{

    public function testBooksAction()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/api/books');
        $this->assertEquals(
            200,
            $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode()
        );
        $this->assertTrue(
            $client->getResponse()->headers->contains(
                'Content-Type',
                'application/json'
            )
        );

    }
}
```

And phpci.yml:

```
build_settings:
    ignore:
        - "vendor"
        - "tests"

setup:
    composer:
        action: "update"

test:
    php_unit:
        config:
            - "app/phpunit.xml"
```

And my phpunit.xml in app/:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.1/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="bootstrap.php.cache"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>../src/ApiBundle/Tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, in the test environment you have to run composer install, otherwise the test environment will contain different versions of the dependencies.

```
setup:
    composer:
        action: "install"
```